# How to get lists items in firebase database

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have following  database structure

[image]

What l am try to do is getting `menulist` nested of `Categories` main list . I have no problem on getting `Categories` but I have tried getting the list of `menulist` . I have empty page .

Code

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.categories = this.af.list("Categories")

    this.categories.snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(changes =>
        changes.map(c => ({ $key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
      )
    ).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.categories = data

      console.log(this.categories);
    })

  }
```

HTML

```
<tbody  *ngFor="let item of categories.menulist">
<tr role="row" class="even text-right">
<td class="text-right">{{item.body}}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{item.title}}</td>  
</tr>
</tbody>
```

any idea how to get `menu list` nested of `Categories` main list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `menulist` is an object, but you need it to be an array.

One solution is to make it an array in TypeScript. For example:

```
subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.categories = data.map(category => {
        const menuKeys = Object.keys(category.menulist || {});
        const menulist = menuKeys.map(menuKey => category.menulist[menuKey]);
        return { ...category, menulist };
    });
    console.log(this.categories);
});
```

Then you need to loop through the `categories` AND through their `menulist` items:

```
<tbody>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let category of categories">
    <tr *ngFor="let item of category.menulist" role="row" class="even text-right">
      <td class="text-right">{{item.body}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{item.title}}</td>  
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

Another solution is to use a [keyvalue pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe), like this:

```
<tbody>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let category of categories">
    <tr *ngFor="let item of category.menulist | keyvalue" role="row"
                                                class="even text-right">
      <td class="text-right">{{item.value.body}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{item.value.title}}</td>  
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

I didn't test these, so watch out for typos.

Also don't forget to `unsubscribe` in `ngOnDestroy`.

---

You also asked how to delete a specific item from some category's menulist.

To do this, you need to know the menulist item's key. Replace

```
const menulist = menuKeys.map(menuKey => category.menulist[menuKey]);
```

with

```
const menulist = menuKeys.map(key => ({...category.menulist[key], key}));
```

and then you can do

```
this.af.object(`Categories/${category.$key}/menulist/${item.key}`).remove();
```

Comment: Thank you for answering , l am still have emtpy page . do you want to share to you my data json in database for testing ?

Comment: i have json in console , but nothing shows in html . check link https://ibb.co/GQhMLK6

Comment: this for https://ibb.co/Y0m4b5z , this for ts https://ibb.co/JjpbNwY

Comment: l am very appreciate , he is working now , thank you

Comment: i have question please , while l am trying to remove specifics item under `menulist` . i removed the main categories list :)) . do you have any idea how to remove specifics item under `menulist`  ? . https://ibb.co/vk0kRCf

Comment: @AliGhassan lol :) common mistake, you're not the only one... that's one reason to add database rules. Anyway, see my edit.

Comment: where should i put this code `this.af.object(`Categories/${category.$key}/menulists/${item.key}`).remove()`

Comment: the items still not remove , after i followed your last edited

Comment: `remove()` is hard to debug, because you can't see what you're deleting, if there's already nothing there. You can do `set('i am deleting here')` instead of `remove()` to see where you're actually deleting.

Comment: @AliGhassan it was a typo, it was `menulists` instead of `menulist`.

Comment: img 1 https://ibb.co/w0pDBw6 and img 2 https://ibb.co/DMrPz8W : img3 https://ibb.co/r4hsSxx

Comment: @AliGhassan I see. Fix the `menulists` typo, then you can do `deleteItem(category.$key, item.key)`. BUT you need to let the `menulist` property as an object instead of array, otherwise the key from `keyvalue` will be the array index (instead of the key in the database). Or don't use `keyvalue`.

Comment: So the point is , How i can make menulist as object instead of array?

Comment: @AliGhassan undo the `data.map...` from my answer. If I were you, I would prefer removing the `keyvalue` pipe instead of undoing the array back to object, though.